# Attach JS events on modal popup when loading new route on it

Tags: jquery

Hello StackOverflow community!

I have one challenge - when I load new children route of index twig template in bootstrap modal, the events of the main script.js are not attached to the newly loaded child in modal.

**Background:** Let's say I have one twig template, (let us call it index.html.twig) which is under base_route. In index.html.twig I have the list of elements which are linked to the edit template of children of base_route.

To open specific route (let us call it edit.twig.html) of individual list element, I used bootstrap modal and in anchor tag of every element in index template I putted:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-child" class="btn btn-primary" data-href="{{ path('part_edit', { 'id': part.id }) }}"> Open </a>
```

Now every element is normally loaded in modal after I click on this anchor tag.

But here is the challenge - because index.html.twig loads JS scripts on page load (and attach events on specific elements), events on modal popup content are not attached, because the modal content does not exist on the page yet. There is no possibility to load prefilled modals on page load, because of load optimization.

And the thing that bothers me is that I must have separate JS events in edit.twig.html. I would like to have these JS events in the main scripts.js file - to have everything more organized. Is there any way I can load main JS file again when modal opens? Or is there any other better approach to attach events that are in the main script file, after the modal popup opens and loads child route template?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to delegate your events e.g. `$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(e) { ... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DarkBee pointed out, you must handle that kind of things with Event Delegation.

If we set events on the element which is not present on the page load the event we listen to won't occur. So we must add the event listener to parent.

When the desired element will load after a page is loaded and we will click on this element (and its parent) the event will be bubbled up.

Then if we listen to the event on parent we can easily check event.target - which will give us clicked child. We then check if we have desired event that has occurred. And after these two checkups, we can then easily run some function.

You can read more about Event bubbling and Event delegation here : https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983